# Compare two data formats(24h and 12AM/PM) in C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, time, timespan

I have following strings:

```
string s1 = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"; // 24H format
string s2 = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM" //12H format
```

I need to compare them in my test (it means that i need to convert s1 to s2 or viceversa). Please help!

Comment: Just parse both to `DateTime` and then compare.

Comment: Convert your Date strings to `DateTime` using their specific format. Please note that for month it is upper case `MM`, and for AM/PM its `tt`, also for Hour part in first Date String, it should be `HH` (upper case) for 24 hours format. See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Convert both to DateTime and then compare them:

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(dt1, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", null) > DateTime.ParseExact(dt2, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
```

Comment: You need MM for the month.

Comment: Also you need `HH` for first date string, since it will be in 24 hours format. *(Without AM/PM)*

Comment: Answer is good, shouldn't be downvoted just because of an error, which he'll probably fix right away anyway

Comment: One more improvement could be to pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null`

Comment: Replace `null` with `DateTimeFormat.InvariantInfo`, otherwise all `/` will be replaced with the localized date separators (in case that they are different).